# Error Query SQL "Invalid use of group function"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying run this query but i got this error "Invalid use of group function". Also tried `group by Año, Mes, Turno;` and same result.

Also I want to multiply the THEN by 100 so that the result is a percentage, I must do it on the same line of THEN or at the end before AS?

```
select year(c.start) as Año, month(c.start) as Mes, s.name as Turno,
SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN u.name ='Jorge Robles Ruiz'
        THEN SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,c.start,c.end)/3600) /
            SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,s.startTime,s.endTime)/3600)
        ELSE 0
    END
) AS 'Jorge Robles Ruiz',
SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN u.name ='Ricardo Jarquín'
        THEN SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,c.start,c.end)/3600) /
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,s.startTime,s.endTime)/3600)
        ELSE 0
    END
) AS 'Ricardo Jarquín' 
from `cicles` as `c` 
inner join `users` as `u` on `u`.`id` = `c`.`opId` and `u`.`companies_id` = `c`.`companies_id` 
inner join `shifts` as `s` on `s`.`id` = `c`.`shiftId` and `s`.`companies_id` = `c`.`companies_id` 
where `c`.`start` 
    between 2018-12-01 and 2019-01-11 
    and `c`.`opId` in (1, 2) 
    and `s`.`visible` = 1 
    and `c`.`companies_id` = 1 
    and `c`.`status` = 1 
group by year(c.start), month(c.start), s.name;
```

Thank you guys!

PD. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I mean, you put a `CASE` expression inside a `SUM`...and that expression returns another `SUM`...remove those

Comment: Your English is fine. No need to [ever] apologize.

Comment: I would add an 'order by clause' which matches your 'group by' clause.

Comment: Why are you trying to sum a percentage? I can't see how it makes sense. Sure, sum the hours worked, sum the total hours the shifts were, turn them into a percentage so you can say "this person worked 95% of the hours they were allocated on shift" or whatever, but if you sum their percentages, you'll get lazy someone who worked only 50% per shift for 20 shifts reporting as having worked 1000%

Comment: You can't nest aggregate functions. So you can't have `SUM()` in the `CASE` that's inside `SUM()`.

Comment: much better to include your sample Data and expected output.

Comment: Yes it worked just removing the SUM inside at case,, thank everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `SUM()` inside `SUM()`, and I don't think you need them both here. I think you should write:

```
SUM(IF(u.name = 'Jorge Robles Ruiz', TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,c.start,c.end), 0))
    / SUM(IF(u.name = 'Jorge Robles Ruiz', TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,s.startTime,s.endTime), 0))
    / 3600 AS 'Jorge Robles Ruiz',
```

To make it a percentage, multiply by `100` at the end, or just change `/ 3600` to `/ 36`.